# Angular js $form.valid is not working

Tags: angularjs, validation

I am working with Angular 1.6.4 version in my project.

I am using the following template for create user details.Here I am making some validations for the fields, until it fulfills the validation, save button will not be enabled.

This is working fine, and error messages for validation works fine in creating users.

I am using the same page to update users, while the user details will be populated in textfields, Here the save button is not enabled even though user details have been populated.

Can anyone assist here in this.

Here is my code,

```
<form name="userForm">
<div class="header-buttons3">
    <button type="button" class="header-button-save btn" ng-disabled="userForm.$invalid" ng-click="submitUserForm()"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>SAVE</button>      
    <button type="button" class="header-button-cancel"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>CANCEL</button>  

  </div> 
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-11 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="x_content">
                <br>
                <div class="form-row row">
                    <div class="form-group required col-md-3">
                        <label for="first name" class="control-label">FIRST NAME</label>
                        <span class="after">*</span> <input class="form-control"
                            ng-class="{validbr: showfn==='false', invalidbr: showfn }"
                            ng-focus="showfn=false"
                            ng-blur="showfn=userForm.firstName.$invalid" id="firstname"
                            class="form-control" ng-model="user.firstName"
                            ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z]*$/" name="firstName" ng-maxlength="30"
                            maxlength="30" required placeholder="Enter First Name" />
                        <div style="color: Red"
                            ng-show="showfn &&  userForm.firstName.$error.required">Error
                            - First Name Required</div>
                        <div style="color: Red"
                            ng-show="showfn &&  userForm.firstName.$error.pattern">Error
                            - Enter only Character</div>
                        <div style="color: Red"
                            ng-show="showfn &&  userForm.firstName.$error.maxlength">Error
                            - Need 30 char max</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group required col-md-3">
                        <label for="last name" class="control-label">LAST NAME</label> <span
                            class="after">*</span> <input class="form-control"
                            ng-class="{validbr: showln==='false', invalidbr: showln }"
                            ng-focus="showln=false"
                            ng-blur="showln=userForm.lastName.$invalid" id="lastname"
                            ng-model="user.lastName" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z]*$/"
                            name="lastName" ng-maxlength="50" maxlength="50" required
                            placeholder="Enter Last Name" />
                        <div style="color: Red"
                            ng-show="showln &&  userForm.lastName.$error.required">Error
                            - Last Name Required</div>
                        <div style="color: Red"
                            ng-show="showln &&  userForm.lastName.$error.pattern">Error
                            - Enter only Character</div>
                        <div style="color: Red"
                            ng-show="showln &&  userForm.lastName.$error.maxlength">Error
                            - Need 50 char max</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group required col-md-3">
                        <label for="inputEmail4" class="control-label">EMAIL
                            ADDRESS</label> <span class="after">*</span>                            
                        <input type="email" readonly  class="form-control"
                            ng-class="{validbr: showem==='false', invalidbr: showem }"
                            ng-focus="showem=false"
                            ng-blur="showem=userForm.emailId.$invalid" id="emailId"
                            ng-model="user.emailId" name="emailId" ng-maxlength="70"
                            maxlength="70" required placeholder="Enter Email Address" />
                        <div style="color: Red"
                            ng-show="showem &&  userForm.emailId.$error.required">Error
                            - Email address Required</div>
                        <div style="color: Red"
                            ng-show="showem &&  userForm.emailId.$error.email">Error -
                            Not a valid email address</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group required col-md-3">
                        <label for="inputEmail4" class="control-label">USER STATUS
                            </label><br/>
                        <label>
                           <input type="radio" ng-model="user.active" ng-value="false">
                            IN ACTIVE
                          </label>
                          <label>
                            <input type="radio" ng-model="user.active" ng-value="true">
                            ACTIVE
                          </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-row row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                        <label for="mobile phone" class="col-form-label">MOBILE
                            PHONE</label> <input class="form-control" id="mobileNumber"
                            ng-class="{validbr: showmn==='false', invalidbr: showmn }"
                            ng-focus="showmn=false"
                            ng-blur="showmn=userForm.mobileNumber.$invalid"
                            ng-model="user.mobileNumber" name="mobileNumber"
                            ng-minlength="14" ng-maxlength="14" phone-input
                            placeholder="Enter Mobile Phone #" />
                        <div style="color: Red"
                            ng-show="showmn && userForm.mobileNumber.$error.minlength ">Error
                            - Need 10 digits for a Phone #</div>
                        <div style="color: Red"
                            ng-show="showmn  && userForm.mobileNumber.$error.maxlength ">Error
                            - Need 10 digits for a Phone #</div>
                        <!-- <div ng-show="userForm.mobileNumber.$error.minlength">Error - Need 10 digits for a Phone #</div> -->
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                        <label for="Desk Phone" class="col-form-label">DESK PHONE</label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="deskNumber"
                            ng-class="{validbr: showdn==='false', invalidbr: showdn }"
                            ng-focus="showdn=false"
                            ng-blur="showdn=userForm.deskNumber.$invalid" name="deskNumber"
                            ng-model="user.deskNumber" ng-minlength="14" maxlength="14"
                            phone-input placeholder="Enter Desk Phone #" />
                        <div style="color: Red"
                            ng-show="showdn && userForm.deskNumber.$error.minlength">Error
                            - Need 10 digits for a Phone #</div>
                        <div style="color: Red"
                            ng-show="showdn && userForm.deskNumber.$error.maxlength">Error
                            - Need 10 digits for a Phone #</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <!-- <input type ="hidden" ng-model="user.createdBy" name="createdBy" />
    <input type ="hidden" ng-model="user.updatedBy" name="updatedBy" /> -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- 
                    <input type="hidden" ng-value="user.createdBy" name="createdBy" />
                    <input type="hidden" ng-value="user.updatedBy" name="updatedBy" />  -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Add {{ userForm.$error }} to your template, and you'll know what the error(s) is (are).

Comment: @JBNizet, I am new to Angular, please help where to place this {{ userForm.$error }}

Comment: Anywhere inside your template.